# Emulador do Android Studio não inicia

Tags: android, android-studio, emulador

Está retornando os seguintes erros:

```
03:05   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

03:05   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

03:05   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Eu já fiz instalação do HAXM.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O aparelho que estou tentando simular é um Nexus 5X.
Já tentei algumas soluções propostas em alguns fóruns como mudar algumas configurações avançadas do aparelho, porém não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Com outras versões eles rodam bem no emulador? Qual o seu processador?

Comment: É muito melhor você utilizar o cabo USB em um *smartphone*, do que o emulador do Android Studio e até mesmo o Genymotion. O máximo que vc precisa fazer é ativar a depuração USB e o modo desenvolvedor. Te poupa em tempo, processamento e de futuros problemas.
Muito provavelmente seu computador não suporta o recurso de emulação do Android Studio... ou está com os drivers desatualizados!

Comment: Muitas vezes é necessário testar o app em outras API's e/ou modelos de celulares, dependendo do projeto. Se o aplicativo for pra alguma empresa que usará um tipo X de celular, nesse caso é recomendado comprar o mesmo modelo de celular pra ir testando o aplicativo, mas em casos mais genéricos o emulador é a melhor opção.

Comment: Não conheço esse Genymotion. É mais leve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que li acima parece que você não ativou o acelerador em seu hardware ou ele é inexistente.
Veja essas dicas:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Seria importante mencionar o tipo de equipamento e detalhes deste também.
Você pode tentar reiniciando o seu equipamento e ingressando na bios e seguindo o manual ativar o recurso de virtualização da Intel, se realmente for suportado pelo seu hardware. 
Estou sinalizando como possível duplicata de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759022/warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine